# If Username Is Not In Log Set Offline

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, cron

Hello I have a `Log` file that contain current connected users in my `server/app`

For Example this is the current connected users in my server/app

```
John
Sue
Roberto
James
Andrea
```

I want to make a `PHP Script` for `Cron` Job that automatically check if the user is in the `Log` or not.

For example If John is the Log I will set his Status in `database` as Online
Then if Connor is not in the list I will set his Status in `database` as Offline.

Thank you very much for your help

Edit:
I'm using this functions to parse the current users of my server 
https://www.devco.net/archives/2005/04/04/openvpn_status_parser_for_php.php

And I used this code to set their status as Online if they are in Log File

```
foreach($stats['users'] as $user){  
    $username=$user['CommonName'];
    if($user['CommonName'] != "UNDEF"){
        if($user['CommonName']==$user['CommonName']){
            $sql = "UPDATE users SET user_status=1 WHERE user_uname='$username'";
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute();
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:
User Log is like this

```
OpenVPN CLIENT LIST
Updated,Sun Apr 15 22:21:51 2018
Common Name,Real Address,Bytes Received,Bytes Sent,Connected Since
m4rshall,useriphere:48839,25015,21667,Sun Apr 15 22:20:51 2018
ROUTING TABLE
Virtual Address,Common Name,Real Address,Last Ref
10.8.0.6,m4rshall,useriphere:48839,Sun Apr 15 22:21:41 2018
GLOBAL STATS
Max bcast/mcast queue length,0
END
```

Comment: You didn't ask an actual question here.. Where exactly are you having issues?

Comment: I'm having issue in checking the status of User by checking it on Log File I can't get the flow/logic in it, That's why I asked for help to solve it. Edit: Sorry for my grammar.

Comment: But what issues are you having? Can you not read the file? Can you not find each user? You have listed what you need to do but not what problems you are facing...

Comment: My Problem is I don't have any idea how to set their status as Offline if they are not in the Log. I'm using foreach to check if they are in the Log and set their status as Online.

Comment: You'd need to show the code where the problems araise.

Comment: `if($log->userInLog($john)) { $john->status = online; }` ?

Comment: I'm using https://www.devco.net/archives/2005/04/04/openvpn_status_parser_for_php.php to parse/check the users connected in my server and foreach to set their status as Online

Comment: foreach($stats['users'] as $user){  
 $username=$user['CommonName'];
 if($user['CommonName'] != "UNDEF"){
  if($user['CommonName']==$user['CommonName']){
   $sql = "UPDATE users SET user_status=1 WHERE user_uname='$username'";
   $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
   $stmt->execute();
  }
 }
}

Comment: please add the code to your question. Don't paste it as comment, as it's unreadable that way.

Comment: oh sorry i'm new at stackoverflow, added sir @Jeff

Comment: _"how to set their status as Offline if they are not in the Log"_ - the easiest (and maybe quickest) way is to _set all offline_ initially, then do the logic you have (after correction)

Comment: also possible is the other way round: get all users that are stored in db and check against Log. This could be quite expensive though.

Comment: set all offline initially solved my problem :) Thank you very much sir Jeff, I'm stuck in this problem for about 2 hours :3

Comment: Set all users Offline in start of the script then set the users Online if they are in the Log at the end of the script. Thank you again Sir @Jeff

Comment: I'll write it as an answer then. Feel free to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand the easiest (and possible fastest) way would be to *set all offline* beforehand. Then do the logic for online users according to the Log.

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET user_status=0";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

foreach($stats['users'] as $user){  
    $username=$user['CommonName'];
    if($user['CommonName'] != "UNDEF"){
        // this is redundant...
        // if($user['CommonName']==$user['CommonName']){
            $sql = "UPDATE users SET user_status=1 WHERE user_uname='$username'";
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute();
        //}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is one way to do it:**
First of all, read the file which contains the users who are log-in and make array variable of it (every line is a new key).
Then you should run on array variable with foreach method which gives you the users one by one and you need to make a query for the specific user.
Simple code:

```
function readUsers($filePath) {
    if (!file_exists($filePath))
        return array();
    $usersArray = array();
    $file = fopen($filePath, "r");
    while (($line = fgets($file)) !== false) {
        $usersArray[] = $line;
    }
    fclose($file);
    return $usersArray;
}

$usersOnline = readUsers("users.txt"); // Get users online as array
// The first query for rest the status for all users and set it as NOT LOGIN
$sql = 'UPDATE `TABLE` SET `status` = false;';
// The second query for set the new status which is login for array of users.
$sql .= 'UPDATE `TABLE` SET `status` = true WHERE `user` in ';
$usersList = '(';
foreach  ($usersOnline as $value) { // Update user status one by one
    $usersList .= '\''.trim($value).'\',';
}
$sql .= $usersList.');';
// run query for $sql
```

An example of that is the file contains:

```
Lambda
Kanfos
```

The result will be:

```
UPDATE `TABLE` SET `status` = false;
UPDATE `TABLE` SET `status` = true WHERE `user` in ('Lambda','Kanfos',);
```

The reason for using "in" method in the second query is to reduce the number of queries.

There is more than one way to do it and I assume that is not the best way, but it is for your way with an external file that saved on the server.

But the way, I'm sorry for my English, this is not my native language.